# Running a JavaScript function for Ubuntu Webapp integration from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I am trying to intrgrate my website with Ubuntu Unity as a webapp following [the tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/javascript/uwapi-ref.html) on the Ubuntu developers site.

So far, I have this code in my HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function unityReady() {
      // Integrate with Unity!
    }
    var Unity = external.getUnityObject(1.0); 

    Unity.init({name: "My WebApp",
                iconUrl: "http://localhost/my-icon.png",
                onInit: unityReady});
</script>
```

This seems to be working fine. Firefox pops up the message asking if I want to install the web app and I accept it.

Now onto the next bit of the tutorial, I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notificationExampleOne() {
        console.log('hello');
        Unity.Notification.showNotification("This is a test", "New message received", null);
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:notificationExampleOne()">execute</a>
```

This also works fine. If I click on "execute" then `hello` appears in the log and the notification dialogue pops up in Unity just as it should do.

Now what I want to do is have this execute as soon as the page loads. However, I want to do it on the fly instead of putting it in the `OnLoad` of the body tag or anything like that. This is because I will ultimately put it inside a JavaScript conditional statement.

However, I am having trouble getting it to execte at all. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    notificationExampleOne();
</script>
```

When I load the page, `hello` appears in the log so I know that the function is being executed. However, the second line of the function doesn't appear to execute because the notification does not display in Unity.

I even tried wrapping the function call inside JQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        notificationExampleOne();
    });
</script>
```

I get the same result though. The word `hello` appears in the log to confirm that the function ran but the Unity notification doesn't fire.

Comment: did it work. can you share you code. I am getting following errors http://askubuntu.com/questions/322978/wrapcallback-is-not-defined-in-unity-webapps

Comment: No, it still isn't working. I gave up and will try again when there is better support available in the future. I upvoted your question to try to get more people to notice it though. Please do the same for mine!